# Java scrollbar option

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

If you can I would like someone to help me make my java interface with a scrollbar option,so I can go up and down my window.

I need the code to add inside my current code and the specific place where to add it

Here is the code:( I cannot add the scroll pane:(

```
package sms;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;





public class SMS4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


        JRadioButton entp = new JRadioButton("Enterprise");
    JRadioButton linux = new JRadioButton("Linux");
        JRadioButton tkodimi = new JRadioButton("TeoriKodimi");
        JRadioButton ings = new JRadioButton("InxhinieriSofti");
        JRadioButton cmp = new JRadioButton("Kompilator");

        JButton save= new JButton("Save");
        ButtonGroup btnG = new ButtonGroup();
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();

private DefaultTableModel students;
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel students1;
private JTable table1;
private DefaultTableModel students2;
private JTable table2;
private DefaultTableModel students3;
private JTable table3;
private DefaultTableModel students4;
private JTable table4;
    public SMS4() {
    super("Lendet");
    btnG.add(entp);
    btnG.add(linux);
    btnG.add(tkodimi);
    btnG.add(ings);
    btnG.add(cmp);

    pane.add(entp);
    pane.add(linux);
    pane.add(tkodimi);
    pane.add(ings);
    pane.add(cmp);

    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        pane2.add(save, "Center");
        save.addActionListener(this);

        entp.addActionListener(this);
    linux.addActionListener(this);
        tkodimi.addActionListener(this);
        ings.addActionListener(this);
        cmp.addActionListener(this);

        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
           BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Zgjidh lenden:"));
        pane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
           BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Tabela e notave:"));
        pane2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
           BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Ruaj:"));

        // tabela e notave:
//tab 1:
    students = new DefaultTableModel();
    students.addColumn( "Emrat" );
    students.addColumn( "Notat" );


try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:db");
                        Statement st= cn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Nota FROM notat WHERE Emerlende='Arkitekture Aplikimi'");
                                        if(rs!=null){
                                        while(rs.next()){

                                                  String[] student= new String[2];
                         student[0]=rs.getString("Name");
                                                   student[1]=rs.getString("Nota");


                                                      students.addRow(student);
                                            }
                                                    }
 else System.out.println("Gabim.");
table = new JTable(students);

pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table.setVisible(false);

 }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        // end tabela
    //tab 1:
    students1 = new DefaultTableModel();
    students1.addColumn( "Emrat" );
    students1.addColumn( "Notat" );


try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection cn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:db");
                        Statement st1= cn1.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs1= st1.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Nota FROM notat WHERE Emerlende='Linux'");
                                        if(rs1!=null){
                                        while(rs1.next()){

                                                  String[] student1= new String[2];
                         student1[0]=rs1.getString("Name");
                                                   student1[1]=rs1.getString("Nota");


                                                      students1.addRow(student1);
                                            }
                                                    }
 else System.out.println("Gabim.");
table1 = new JTable(students1);

pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table1),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table1.setVisible(false);

 }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        // end tab1
       //tab 2:
     students2 = new DefaultTableModel();
    students2.addColumn( "Emrat" );
    students2.addColumn( "Notat" );


try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:db");
                        Statement st= cn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Nota FROM notat WHERE Emerlende='Teori Kodimi'");
                                        if(rs!=null){
                                        while(rs.next()){

                                                  String[] student2= new String[2];
                         student2[0]=rs.getString("Name");
                                                   student2[1]=rs.getString("Nota");


                                                      students2.addRow(student2);
                                            }
                                                    }
 else System.out.println("Gabim.");
table2 = new JTable(students2);

pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table2),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table2.setVisible(false);

 }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        // end tab2
           //tab 3:
     students3 = new DefaultTableModel();
    students3.addColumn( "Emrat" );
    students3.addColumn( "Notat" );


try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:db");
                        Statement st= cn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Nota FROM notat WHERE Emerlende='Inxhinieri Softi'");
                                        if(rs!=null){
                                        while(rs.next()){

                                                  String[] student3= new String[2];
                         student3[0]=rs.getString("Name");
                                                   student3[1]=rs.getString("Nota");


                                                      students3.addRow(student3);
                                            }
                                                    }
 else System.out.println("Gabim.");
table3 = new JTable(students3);

pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table3),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table3.setVisible(false);

 }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        // end tab3
           //tab 4:
     students4 = new DefaultTableModel();
    students4.addColumn( "Emrat" );
    students4.addColumn( "Notat" );


try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:db");
                        Statement st= cn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Nota FROM notat WHERE Emerlende='Kompilatore'");
                                        if(rs!=null){
                                        while(rs.next()){

                                                  String[] student4= new String[2];
                         student4[0]=rs.getString("Name");
                                                   student4[1]=rs.getString("Nota");


                                                      students4.addRow(student4);
                                            }
                                                    }
 else System.out.println("Gabim.");
table4 = new JTable(students4);

pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table4),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table4.setVisible(false);

 }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        // end tab4
    Container paneg= getContentPane();
        paneg.add(pane, "North");
        paneg.add(pane1, "Center");
        paneg.add(pane2, "South");

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(entp.isSelected() ){
                            students = new DefaultTableModel();
                table.setVisible(true);

            }

 else if (linux.isSelected()) {
                       students1 = new DefaultTableModel();
                table1.setVisible(true);

            }
 else if (tkodimi.isSelected()) {
                       students2 = new DefaultTableModel();
                table2.setVisible(true);

            }
 else if (ings.isSelected())
                        {
                       students3 = new DefaultTableModel();
                    table3.setVisible(true);

            }
 else if (cmp.isSelected()) {
                       students4 = new DefaultTableModel();
                table4.setVisible(true);

            }
    }


   public void frame(){
    SMS4 s4 = new SMS4();
    s4.setSize(700,700);
    s4.setVisible(true);
    s4.setResizable(false);
    s4.setLocation(320,400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) class is what you are looking for. The JavaDocs tell you everything you need to know and even link to a simple to use tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

**Put your component inside a `JScrollPane`.**

Whatever item you wish to scroll, be in a `JPanel` or a `JTextArea`, you should add it to a `JScrollPane` and then add the `JScrollPane` to the panel or other container.

So find wherever you're doing this:

```
container.add(item);
```

Instead, do this:

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(item);
container.add(pane);
```

Comment: Thank you,I think this is the best answer;) I cannot mark it as a good answer:(

Comment: Hi again Erick:( I put the code in my questions,,,can you tell me what to put and where please?:(

Comment: Well, this is pretty much a mess.  I have a hard time even following it.  The indentation is nowhere near consistent.  You also have lots and lots of panes that seem to be confusing things.  Try to simplify things down to just adding one table with a scroll pane.  Then once you see that you've gotten it to work, you can go back to the more complicated scenarios.  This will make sure that the problem is really with the scrollpane and not with one of the other panels or components.